# "-[__NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" error without NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my code, when I press a button to open a popup screen, it is supposed to take data from a website and store that in a string, and then put that string into a textview on the popup screen. When I run the program and press the button to get to the popup screen, I get a SIGABRT error and "-[__NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance". After researching this, I saw that the error comes when you try to reference NSDictionary to a length method. I don't have an NSDictionary in my code, so I don't know what causes the error.

**Error Message**

> [76416:60b] -[**NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x8f8ece0 2014-08-13 16:41:59.248 CWSGui[76416:60b] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI length]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f8ece0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x01c0d1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0198c8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x01caa243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275  3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x01bfd50b ___forwarding_** + 1019
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x01bfd0ee
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14    5   Foundation                          0x015aa4e4 -[NSConcreteAttributedString length] + 42    6   Foundation
>   0x015a9a6c -[NSConcreteAttributedString initWithString:attributes:] +
>   182   7   UIKit                               0x00d5ae9d -[UITextView
>   setText:] + 125   8   CWSGui                              0x0000805e
>   -[SystemLog viewDidAppear:] + 686     9   UIKit                               0x0076f099 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 526
>     10  UIKit                               0x0076f617 -[UIViewController
>   **viewDidAppear:] + 146   11  UIKit                               0x00771014 __64-[UIViewController
>   viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]_block_invoke + 44   12 
>   UIKit                               0x0076f9aa -[UIViewController
>   _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 63    13  UIKit                               0x0066a0d0 ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke_2 + 33  14  UIKit
>
>   0x0066a055 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403    15  UIKit
>
>   0x00669e9a _afterCACommitHandler + 568    16  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x01bd536e
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 30    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01bd52bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers
>   + 399     18  CoreFoundation                      0x01bb3254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01bb29d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467   20  CoreFoundation
>   0x01bb27eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   21  GraphicsServices
>   0x03a3d5ee GSEventRunModal + 192  22  GraphicsServices
>   0x03a3d42b GSEventRun + 104   23  UIKit
>   0x0064cf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225   24  CWSGui
>   0x00008e2d main + 141     25  libdyld.dylib
>   0x024be701 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

**View Did Appear**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSUserDefaults *ipdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    IPString = [ipdefaults objectForKey:@"IP"];
    NSString *http = @"http://";
    NSString *IPMiddle = [http stringByAppendingString:IPString];
    NSString *IPFinal = [IPMiddle stringByAppendingString:@"/tasks"];
    NSLog(@"Final IP: %@", IPFinal);

    //array stuff from the ip

    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //make a connection
    [self getIPWithIP:IPFinal];

    NSString *str=@"http://example.com";

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSString *string = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];


    NSLog(@"Your JSON Object: %@", string);
    textField.text = string;
 }
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: "I don't have an NSDictionary in my code" - Objective-C is a quite weakly typed language, the lack of declaration does not mean that you are not operating with dictionaries. Probably, the return value of `+[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:]` is not a string but - apparently - a dictionary. You need to actually **understand** what you are doing. Blindly hammerin'-copyin'-pastin' code ain't gonna do any good.

Comment: I'm betting `NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData` is returning a dictionary, not a string.

Comment: `NSLog(@"Your JSON Object: %@", string); textField.text = string;`  "string" isn't one. You're taking the JSON directly from the parser, which means it's certain to be either an NSArray or an NSDictionary.

Comment: As @TheParamagneticCroissant suggests, you need to *understand* what you're doing.  Simply copying code, *especially* when dealing with JSON, will almost always get you into trouble.  For starters, go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes and you gotta know it before you can do anything else.  (Also, NSLog is your friend here.)

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks, I read that site and it helped me understand it.

Comment: This worked for me -[NSDictionaryI length], I was using the NSDictionary object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

is **never** returning a string. Either a NSArray or a NSDictionary. (The documentation only promises: *A Foundation object from the JSON data in data, or nil if an error occurs.* So it might be another type in future).

You error starts with

> -[NSDictionaryI length]:

so in your case it is a dictionary (NSDictionaryI is a concrete immutable subclass of NSDictionary).

Just because you type the variable `NSString` it doesn't change the object assigned to it.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to id response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];  and from there I converted it into a string which I displayed in the text field.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the length of an `NSString` that is actually an `NSDictionary`. It's probably the result of some JSON parsing.